# Variable File Path in the Commandline Lazarus/Free Pascal

Tags: lazarus

I want to execute an external program which is called 'copy.bat' located at my desktop 'C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\RunProgram\lib\x86_64-win64'. If I want to run the Program on someone else's Computer/ Account where 'copy.bat' is in the same folder it doesn't work, because the username changes.
My question: is there any way to use a variable username?

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work...

```
  var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Runprogram:TProcess;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RunProgram := TProcess.Create(nil);
  RunProgram.CommandLine := '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RunProgram\lib\x86_64-win64\Copy.bat';
  RunProgram.Execute;
  RunProgram.Free;


end;
```

P.S. If I enter this path 'C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\RunProgram\lib\x86_64-win64\Copy.bat' it works.

Comment: [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx)

Comment: @David Heffernan I still don´t know how to implement this. Maybe you can help me a bit further.

Comment: Some websearch would yield many examples.

Comment: I´m really sorry but I´m new to Lazarus and Delphi (only knew the verry basics) and just looking up the command has told me nothing I could work with. Maybe you could spear some time and give me a link to a site where the use of the command is well and easy explained:

Comment: I linked to the documentation. Did you not understand it?

Comment: No, not really or better I don´t know how I should use it.

Comment: Well, you probably need to do some more basic learning. This task is out of your reach right now.

Comment: There was only a C++ function given how should I use it for Lazarus

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Function "GetEnvironmentVariable"

```
userP := GetEnvironmentVariable(String('USERPROFILE'));
RunProgram.CommandLine := userP + '\Desktop\RunProgram\lib\x86_64-win64\Copy.bat';
```